# Generators of an ideal in rings of power series

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series, ideals

Please help me for solving a homework.

> Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]]$ the ring of power series over $k$.
>   If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $(I:x_1)=(I:x_2)=(I:x_3)=\cdots=(I:x_{r})\neq
> (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $(I:x_{r+1})=(I:x_{r+2})=\cdots=(I:x_n)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$
>   for some $r\in\{1,2,\ldots,n \} $, and also $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^3 \subseteq I $, then what can we say about the generators of $I$ and the number $n$ (is it one)?

Comment: Have you tried $I = (x_{r+1}, \dots, x_n) m + m^3$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal?